# Why is the 'info[]' of the struct records giving errors?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, for-loop

This program uses class and takes the info of employees from a file. I have mentioned the file below too. I have also mentioned the output i received even though there are error. There is something wrong in the output too but I think it is because of the info error that it's getting.

While running this program, I got this error message:

```
Error: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'info' was corrupted.
```

There's also this message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00950A89 in employee.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun.
```

//   The used file for this program is:

```
A.Smith                       20001 25 40
T.Philip                      20002 20 35
S.LOng                        20003 15 50
G.Santos                      20004 30 30
F.Farkas                      20005 22 55
```

// The output after running even with the errors is:

```
 This week's employee history

 Name           Id            Rate          Hours
*  A.Smith     20001         $25/h        40h
* T.Philip     20002         $20/h        35h
*   S.LOng     20003         $15/h        50h
* G.Santos     20004         $30/h        30h
* F.Farkas     20005         $22/h        55h


This week's payment

 Name               Payment
* ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠         $0        <----------There is this error too
*  T.Philip         $700
*    S.LOng         $825
*  G.Santos         $900
*   A.Smith         $1000


* The average wages of the employees: $685.00
```

// The code is:

```
/*
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string> 
#include<iomanip> 
*/
using namespace std;

struct records {
    char name[50] = {};
    char id[5] = {};
    int rate = 0;
    int hours = 0;
    int pay = 0;
};

void take(records array[], const int a);
int calculator(records array[], const int a);
void swap(records array[], const int a);   
double Average(records array[], int a);

ifstream infile;

int main()

{
    const int n = 5;
```

This is the first time info is declared:

```
    struct records info[n];
    double averageWages;
    int overTime = 0, i;
    infile.open("Project 3.dat");

    cout << "\n This week's employee history \n" << endl;

    if (infile.is_open()) {
        cout << " Name           Id            Rate          Hours  " << endl;
```

Here take function uses info of the struct:

```
        take(info, n);

        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "This week's payment\n" << endl;
        cout << " Name               Payment" << endl;
```

Also here other functions use info:

```
        calculator(info, n);
        swap(info, n);

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << "*" << setw(10) << info[i].name << setw(10) << "$" << info[i].pay << endl;
        }
        averageWages = Average(info, n);

        cout << "\n\n" << "* The average wages of the employees: $" << averageWages << endl << endl;
    }

    else {
        cerr << "Error! file cannot open." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

// Taking records:

```
void take(records array[], const int a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {

        while (infile >> array[i].name >> array[i].id >> array[i].rate >> array[i].hours) {
            cout << "*" << setw(9) << array[i].name << setw(10) << array[i].id << setw(10) << "$" << array[i].rate << "/h" << setw(10) << array[i].hours << "h      " << endl;
        }
    } infile.close();
}
```

//swap records to arrange it according to total payment received

```
void swap(records array[], const int a) {
    bool tf; //true or false

    do {
        tf = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {

            if (array[i].pay > array[i + 1].pay) {
                swap(array[i], array[i + 1]);
                tf = true;
            }
        }
    } while (tf);

    records temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < a - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a; ++j)
        {
            if (array[i].pay > array[j].pay)
            {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

To calculate average:

double Average(records array[], const int a) {

    double total = 0;
    double average;

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        total = total + (array[i].pay);
        average = total / a;
    }

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);
    return (total / a);
}
```

// To calculate the salary:

```
int calculator(records array[], const int a) {



    infile.open("Project 3.dat");

    if (infile.is_open()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            infile >> array[i].name >> array[i].id >> array[i].rate >> array[i].hours;

            if (array[i].hours > 40) {
                int   overTime = (array[i].hours - 40)*1.5;
                array[i].pay = ((array[i].rate) * 40) + (overTime*(array[i].rate));
            }
            else {
                array[i].pay = (array[i].rate)*(array[i].hours);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            return (array[i].pay);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: many things can be removed from your code while still being able to reproduce the problem, lots of blank lines for example make it hard to read

Comment: you are reading out of bounds `array[i].pay > array[i + 1].pay` where condition is `i < a`, for `a` as size of array.

Comment: Run valgrind or address sanitizer.

Comment: On a very quick look, your IDs are 5 characters long, but your string buffer for IDs is only 5 bytes long.  You won't have enough space for the null terminator, which means just about every string-related function is going to behave extremely unpredictably and often dangerously.  Read up on how C-strings work and are stored.  This is probably not the only problem in the program.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find all potential problems with that fragmented code, but you'd be better off using `std::string`s instead of `char[]`. They are safer and also has a lot of built-in functions. They also work well with misc. functions in the STL.

Your `struct records info[n];` will only hold `n` (5) elements. Use a standard container, like a `std::vector` instead in case you'd like to add more entries to the file.

Reading and writing to files can usually be done using custom stream operators and all the free functions you have to deal with a number of records could be collected in a class of its own. I've made one `record` struct and one `Records` class to demonstrate how they could be used Together.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct record {
    std::string name{};
    std::string id{};
    int rate = 0;
    int hours = 0;
    int pay = 0;

    // stream operators for reading/writing a record
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, record&);
    friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream&, const record&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const record&);
};

// populate a record from an istream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, record& r) {
    std::string line;
    // get a line and check that it's > 30 chars long
    if(std::getline(is, line) && line.size()>30) {
        // extract the name and remove trailing spaces
        r.name = line.substr(0, 30);
        auto pos = r.name.find_last_not_of(' ');
        if(pos != std::string::npos)
            r.name = r.name.substr(0, pos+1);

        // put the rest of the line in a stringstream
        std::stringstream ss(line.substr(30));
        // and extract the rest of the fields
        if(ss >> r.id >> r.rate >> r.hours) {
            // calculate pay
            r.pay = r.rate * r.hours;
        } else { // if extraction fails, set the stream in fail mode
            is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        }
    } else is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);

    return is;
}

// streaming a record to an ofstream (like a file)
std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& os, const record& r) {
    os << std::setw(30) << std::left << r.name.substr(0, 30) << r.id << " " << r.rate << " " << r.hours << "\n";
    return os;
}

// streaming a record to a generic ostream (like std::cout)
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const record& r) {
    os << "* " << std::setw(30) << std::left << r.name << std::right << r.id
       << " $" << r.rate << "/h " << r.hours << "h $" << std::setw(4) << r.pay;
    return os;
}

class Records { // a class to maintain a number of "record"s
    std::vector<record> m_records{}; // stores all "record"s
public:
    Records(const std::string& filename) {
        record tmp;
        std::ifstream e(filename); // open file
        // and extract one record at a time and put it in m_records.
        while(e>>tmp) m_records.emplace_back(std::move(tmp));
    }

    // sum on any member in "record"
    template <typename field>
    auto Sum(field f) const {
        return std::accumulate(m_records.begin(), m_records.end(), 0,
                    [&](int a, const record& b) { return a + (b.*f); });
    }

    // average of any member in "record"
    template <typename field>
    auto Average(field f) const {
        return static_cast<double>(Sum(f)) / m_records.size();
    }

    // sorting on any member in "record"
    template <typename field, typename T>
    void Sort(field f, const T& cmp) {
        std::sort(m_records.begin(), m_records.end(),
                [&](const record& a, const record& b){ return cmp(a.*f, b.*f); });
    }

    // return the number of "record" elements
    std::vector<record>::size_type size() const { return m_records.size(); }

    // access an element via subscript
    record& operator[](std::vector<record>::size_type idx) { return m_records[idx]; }
    const record& operator[](std::vector<record>::size_type idx) const { return m_records[idx]; }

    // iterators to use in for-loops
    std::vector<record>::const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return m_records.cbegin(); }
    std::vector<record>::const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return m_records.cend(); }
    std::vector<record>::const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return cbegin(); }
    std::vector<record>::const_iterator end() const noexcept { return cend(); }
    std::vector<record>::iterator begin() noexcept { return m_records.begin(); }
    std::vector<record>::iterator end() noexcept { return m_records.end(); }

    // stream operator to show all records
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Records&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Records& R) {
    os << "  Name                            Id  Rate  Hrs  Pay\n";
    for(const auto& r : R) std::cout << r << "\n";

    os << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed;
    os << "Average pay         : $" << std::setw(7) << R.Average(&record::pay) << "\n";
    os << "        rate        : $" << std::setw(7) << R.Average(&record::rate) << "\n";
    os << "        hours worked:  " << std::setw(7) << R.Average(&record::hours) << "h\n";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    // create a "Records" entity called "info" by reading a file
    Records info("Project 3.dat");

    // misc sorting and showing the result
    std::cout << "Sorted as read from the file:\n";
    std::cout << info;

    std::cout << "\nSorted according to name:\n";
    info.Sort(&record::name, std::less<std::string>());
    std::cout << info;

    std::cout << "\nSorted according to id:\n";
    info.Sort(&record::id, std::less<std::string>());
    std::cout << info;

    std::cout << "\nSorted according to pay:\n";
    info.Sort(&record::pay, std::greater<int>());
    // output example using iterators:
    for(auto& rec : info) {
        std::cout << rec << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "\nSorted according to rate:\n";
    info.Sort(&record::rate, std::greater<int>());
    std::cout << info;

    std::cout << "\nSorted according to hours:\n";
    info.Sort(&record::hours, std::greater<int>());
    std::cout << info;

    // example using subscript, operator[]
    if(info.size()>2) {
        std::cout << "\ninfo[2] = " << info[2] << "\n";
    }
}
```